# How to access the value of a mapping variable with Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a variable of a mapping type that I want to access the value of from the front end:

```
mapping(address => uint) public etherBalanceOf;
```

I store the contract in a state

```js
const test = new web3.eth.Contract(test.abi, test.networks[netId].address)
this.setState({test})
```

and make the web3 call as following:

```js
if(this.state.test !== "undfined") {
  try {
    const depositBalance = await this.state.test.etherBalanceOf.call(this.state.account)
    console.log(depositBalance)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Error, checking balance", e)
  }
}
```

But, I get an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

`etherBalanceOf` takes in an address as argument

Instead of

```
const depositBalance = await this.state.test.etherBalanceOf.call(this.state.account)
```

pass in an address to `etherBalanceOf(address)`

```
const depositBalance = await this.state.test.etherBalanceOf(this.state.account).call()
```